# Extract certain lines and manipulate them quickly

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a big file (100G) which looks like below (I simplified the file: 1-there are actually much more characters per line, 2- lines do not start with numbers)

```
@1ab
2sdasd
3asd
4asdf
@5fhd
6dhg
7ttht
8fgn
@9aghf
10adfgh
```

All lines whose line number `%4==1` has a `@` at the beginning. I'd like to extract those lines AND their next lines, and replace `@` with '>', and output it into a new file.

Output will look like:

```
>1ab
2sdasd
>5fhd
6dhg
>9aghf
10adfgh
```

Here is my solution:

```
awk 'NR%4==1 || NR%4==2 {gsub("@",">"); print}' infile > outfile
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: You aren't going to find anything all that much fast than what you've written.  The `gsub()` might be overkill; it will swap all `@` signs, not just the first.  You could use `sub()` instead, which stops after the first match -- a slight performance benefit.  You also do the substitution on both lines of each pair, but you only need to do it on the first.  Fixing that might speed things up a little.  But the differences won't be all that dramatic, I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk '{ k=NR%4; if(k==1) print ">"substr($0,2); else if(k==2) print }' infile > outfile
```

- `k=NR%4` - coefficient, calculated for each record only once

---

The `outfile` contents (for your current input):

```
>1ab
2sdasd
>5fhd
6dhg
>9aghf
10adfgh
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk`, with/out [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html)

```
$ cat infile
@1ab
2sdasd
3asd
4asdf
@5fhd
6dhg
7ttht
8fgn
@9aghf
10adfgh

$ awk 'FNR%4==1{sub(/@/,">");print; getline; print}' infile
>1ab
2sdasd
>5fhd
6dhg
>9aghf
10adfgh

# without using getline
awk 'f{print; f=0; next}FNR%4==1{sub(/@/,">");print; f=1; next}' infile
>1ab
2sdasd
>5fhd
6dhg
>9aghf
10adfgh
```

> The `getline` function reads the next line and moves the script to
>   it, nothing but `$0` from next input record; set `NF`, `NR`, `FNR`, `RT`

Comment: Thanks! this is faster than mine but since @RomanPerekhrest solution is .3% faster, I accepted that one :)

Comment: @havij sure, not an issue, you still can replace `sub(/@/,">");print;` with `print ">"substr($0,2);`

Answer (score 1):

If the at characters only occur as the "record separators", you could go with `fgrep` and `tr`, e.g.:

```
fgrep --no-group-separator -A1 '@' infile | tr @ \>
```

This is an order of magnitude faster than your awk solution.

To stick with the modulus 4, it is 4 times faster to do it with GNU sed, e.g.:

```
sed -n '1~4 { N; s/^@/>/p; }' infile
```

Output in both cases:

```
>1ab                                                                
2sdasd
>5fhd
6dhg
>9aghf
10adfgh
```

Comment: `sed` solution runs very close to `awk`, but `fgrep` is not correct because `@` appears in other places (other than at the beginning of `%4==0` lines), replacing it with `grep --no-group-separator -A1 '^@' infile | tr @ \>` gives almost the same time as `awk`.

Comment: @havij: I was comparing to GNU awk, which version of awk are you testing against?